# reducing response size

Tags: html, django, http, http-headers

I am working on a web application and I am using polling approach to check if there is any update needed. These polling requests occur in every 1 or 2 seconds. The size of the response is 240 bytes if there is no update needed(An empty response is returned in that case) and around 10 KBs which is the size of the content itself. My problem is, since it returns at least 240 B in every seconds approximately, is there a way to optimize this response by pushing the boundaries a bit more?

When I checked the contents of the response, I saw that the 50 bytes are essential for me(session id and status code). However, there are some information in the header such as connection type, timeout and content-type. These settings will be same for each request of this type(i.e. it always requires content type as: "text/html; carset=utf-8"). So, can I just assume these settings in client side and prevent the server from sending these header info?

I am using django on the server side and jQuery for sending ajax requests by the way. Also, any type of push technology is out of question for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this kind of problem is "long polling".  The polling client will send a request, and the webserver checks to see if there is an update.  If there is not, the webserver sleeps for a second or two and then checks again in a loop, without sending a response.  As soon as this loop sees an update, it sends a response.  To the client web browser, it will look like the server is congested and taking a long time to respond, but actually the relevant data is being transmitted promptly and the "no data" responses are simply being skipped.

I'd recommend adding a timeout to the loop -- say 30 or 60 seconds -- after which the webserver would reply with "no data" as usual.  Even just a 30 second cycle would cut your empty response load by a factor of 15-30.

Caveat: I've read about this kind of implementation but I haven't tried it myself.  You will need to test compatibility with various web browsers to ensure that this fairly nonstandard method doesn't cause issues on the client side.

Comment: I checked long-polling. It seems reasonable. However, doesn't it causes overloading in the server side when you do busy sleep all the time. I do not have much knowledge about performance issues on server.

Comment: Assuming you use a sleep mechanism like time.sleep(2), it won't be any less performant than normal polling.  It should actually save CPU time -- but it will probably consume more memory on the host machine because each request thread is in memory for much longer.  Whether that makes sense for your application or not depends on the specifics of your situation and how many users you have.  However, it will definitely save on bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

It does add up, but not as much as you think. If you polled every sec for a full hour, you'd have only used 864K, less than a typical webpage would require with an unprimed cache. Even if you did it for a full day, you're talking about ~20M. Maybe if you're someone like Twitter, you might need to be concerned about this, but I doubt you'll be getting anywhere near the traffic it would take for this to actually be problematic.

Nevertheless, you can of course customize the headers of the request, but what if any impact this will have on the client will be a matter to testing. Some headers can probably be dropped, but others may surprise you, and it technically could vary browser to browser, as well.